# Breeze Query Slow but Ajax calls are fast

Tags: jquery, performance, breeze, single-page-application, hottowel

I have a single page application with a repository and unit of work.l The implementation is similar to that of the project [TempHire](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/temphire-sample). I load my metadata in the shell.js. My unit of work and repository are in difference projects and are referenced in my project. Also, my unit of work uses EFContextProvider to get Data.

However, my queries are very slow to execute. Breeze queries are very slow (and very often time out). A query like `unitofwork.objectname.fetch()` (where fetch get data from a path, `controllername/Actionname`) will take long.  However, my ajax request are fast. If I make the same call to the same action `controllername/Actionname`, the response will be very fast.

I am not sure whether I provided enough information (since I do not know where to look for the problem) but will clarify if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First check and make sure that metadata is only being retrieved once.  This should happen just before the first query is executed. If you see it being retrieved over and over then there is something else going on in your app.  There are several other posts on SO where people have inadvertently done this.

So the net is that your FIRST query on any EntityManager can be slow because it is doing both a metadata query followed by a data query, but every other query after this point should be pretty fast.

Comment: The first request can also be slow while the web API and EF spin up. But if it is continually slow, you should open the network tab in the browser tools (or Fiddler) and see what is flowing over the wire. Lots of requests? The expected number? Exactly one metadata request or multiple? And how many entities are you returning in a request, btw?

Comment: manager.fetchMetadata() will give you an error (something like cant do it twice) if you call it over and over :)

Comment: @Didar_Uranov not if, as many do, you spin up a brand new EntityManager each time. Each manager is its own world with its own MetadataStore unless you decide otherwise (as you usually would) with something like `em2 = em.createEmptyCopy()`.